# Forming a palindrome with random 7 letter word

Tags: combinatorics

Hi so i'm working out a problem from combinatorics where it says to solve for probability of a palindrom using n=7 letter word.

now the solution says to pick 4 letters and arrange them as (1,2,3,4,3,2,1).  however I can form a palindrome using 2 letters correct?  (1,1,1,2,1,1,1) ?   If this is the okay, with repeat letters, then the problem is more complicated?

is this the right definition of a palindrom? can't i have more than 1 letter drawn?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Are you supposed to compute the probability that a $7$ letter word is a palindrome? It is not clear what the alphabet $\Sigma$ is here. Is it simply `[a-z]`?

Comment: yes only lower case letters.

Answer (score 3):

There are $26^7$ possible $7$ letter words that can be formed using the alphabet `[a-z]`.

A palindrome of length $7$ has the form: $abcdcba$, where $a,b,c,d$ do not need to be distinct, so you can choose a letter $\in$ `[a-z]` for each one. Thus, there are $26^4$ total palindromes of length $7$.

The probability of choosing one is:
$$
\frac{26^4}{26^7} = \frac{1}{26^3} \approx 0.0000569
$$